# How do I express a function that takes a set of values?

Tags: arithmetic

I have a function that I as a programmer would express like this in pseudo-code:

```
myFunc(int[x0, x1, ... xn]){
    return 1/((1/x0)+(1/x1)+...+(1/xn));
}
```

How is this expression written in a mathematical form?

Comment: What happens if you input $x_0=0$?

Comment: That is undefined.

Comment: Then mathematicians would not call this a function (unless you restrict to the domain on which it **is** defined).

Comment: How would you specify a limitation like this in the below provided answers?

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks, I misread the post and removed the answer. Unfortunately, typos tend to generate more downvotes than solutions of hard problems generate upvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A\subset(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})^{n+1}$ be defined as $$A=\left\{(x_0,\ldots,x_n)\in(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})^{n+1}\mid \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^{-1}\neq 0\right\}$$ and let $f\colon A\to\mathbb{R}$ be given by $$f(x_0,\ldots,x_n)=\left(\sum_{i=0}^n x_i^{-1}\right)^{-1}.$$

---

This takes in to account that one of the above questions isn't defined on its assumed domain (either the $(n+1)$-fold cartesian product of the integers, or the product of the integers without zero. The above function is *actually* well defined - that is, every element in its domain is mapped, by $f$, to a unique, well-defined element in the codomain.

Answer (score 0):

AD's answer is slightly incorrect... your function would be written as
$$f(x_0,\ldots,x_n) = \frac{1}{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{x_k}}$$
or perhaps
$$f(x_0,\ldots,x_n) =\left(\sum_{k=0}^n x_k^{-1}\right)^{-1}.$$

Notice also that it is very closely related to the harmonic mean.

Comment: Because of the missing inversion, right? And your two examples is equal for all inputs, just a different way to express the same mathematical relation?

Comment: @Alex Yes, and yes.